# How to setup scrollView adding items with animation to simulate a text messaging UI

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I am making an app where the user writes a post with a Category, Title and Body. The composting process I want to work as if the user is having a conversation with someone, so it looks identical to a messaging UI. I have 3 prewritten responses that are randomly generated and change based on the category. I tried to follow a messaging style build with a recycler view, but I am new to Java and android studio and could not figure out how to alter the code to suit my needs, as I do not have the messaging backend. I found scroll view to be a simpler solution for what I need to do, but at the moment I can't seem to add the text bubbles in, after each step, only hide them and unhide them once they are ready to show so It does not feel like a messaging UI.

This is the LinearLayout in the scroll view holding the text bubble textViews:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/response1TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_green"
            android:maxWidth="240dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#34aacf"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="458dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleBubbleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_green"
            android:maxWidth="240dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#34aacf"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="288dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="416dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/response2TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_green"
            android:maxWidth="240dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#34aacf"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="361dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageBubbleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_green"
            android:maxWidth="240dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#34aacf"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="288dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="319dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/response3TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_green"
            android:maxWidth="240dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#34aacf"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="284dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Ideally, I would rather add the textViews programmatically after each step, and have them animate in similar to a texting UI.

The view is a fragment and here is how I am setting it up initially:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    Responses responses;

    DocumentReference responsesList = db.collection("responses").document("postResponses");
   responsesList.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
           DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

           positiveFirstResponses = (List<String>) document.get("positiveFirstResponses");
           positiveSecondResponses = (List<String>) document.get("positiveSecondResponses");
           positiveThirdResponses = (List<String>) document.get("positiveThirdResponses");

           balancedFirstResponses = (List<String>) document.get("balancedFirstResponses");
           balancedSecondResponses = (List<String>) document.get("balancedSecondResponses");
           balancedThirdResponses = (List<String>) document.get("balancedThirdResponses");

           negativeFirstResponses = (List<String>) document.get("negativeFirstResponses");
           negativeSecondResponses = (List<String>) document.get("negativeSecondResponses");
           negativeThirdResponses = (List<String>) document.get("negativeThirdResponses");

           Log.d("positive ", positiveFirstResponses.toString());
       }
   });

    View postView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, container, false);

    scrollView = postView.findViewById(R.id.messageScrollView);

    chatBox = postView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_chatbox);
    sendButton = postView.findViewById(R.id.button_chatbox_send);

    response1 = postView.findViewById(R.id.response1TextView);
    titleBubble = postView.findViewById(R.id.titleBubbleTextView);
    response2 = postView.findViewById(R.id.response2TextView);
    messageBubble = postView.findViewById(R.id.messageBubbleTextView);
    response3 = postView.findViewById(R.id.response3TextView);

    response1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    titleBubble.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    response2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    messageBubble.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    response3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    guideLabel = postView.findViewById(R.id.guideLabel);
    guideLabel.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    guideLabel.setText("Choose a category");
    guideLabel.setTextSize(26);

     positive = postView.findViewById(R.id.postHeart);
     balanced = postView.findViewById(R.id.postBalanced);
     negative = postView.findViewById(R.id.postTear);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enterButtonAction();
        }
    });
    positive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setPositive();
        }
    });
    balanced.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setBalanced();
        }
    });
    negative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setNegative();
        }
    });


    chatBox.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                switch (keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        enterButtonAction();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return postView;
}
```

How could I add the text bubbles programmatically and include an animation for them, to simulate a text messaging UI? Thank you.

(The text bubbles should be gravity Right and Left rather than Center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be harder for you to implement the RecyclerView, but RecyclerView supports animations which ScrollView doesn't support and therefore I recommend you using a RecyclerView for the animation.

https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213

I have added a link to read about recyclerView animations since it is not possible to implement many animations in ScrollView